# Deleting child item from Linq2Sql bound TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, mvvm, treeview

I'm having a TreeView control in WPF which displays a list of tasks on the first level. Each task has a list of persons. Both the tasks and persons are stored in a database. I wrote 2 viewmodel classes which encapsulate the Linq2Sql classes. The TreeView consists of 2 hierarchical DataTemplates which refers to the viewmodel classes. Displaying the data works well and I can add task and persons without any problems.

But now I have the problem that I want to delete a person underneath a task from a contextmenu.  My problem is that I am not able to access the parent task and therefore cannot update the persons collection. I know which person to delete but not to which task it belongs.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Gerrit

```
    using System;

class ViewmodelPerson
{
    public ViewmodelPerson(LinqPerson P)
    {
        DBPerson = P;
    }
    LinqPerson DBPerson;
}

public class ViewmodelTask
{

    public ViewmodelTask(LinqTask DBTask)
    {
        this.DBTask = DBTask;
        _Persons = from P in DBTask.Person
                   select new ViewModelPerson(P);
    }

    LinqTask DBTask;

    List<ViewmodelPerson> _Persons;
    List<ViewmodelPerson> Persons
    {
        get
        {
            return _Persons;
        }
    }

    public void AddPerson(ViewmodelPerson P)
    {

    }
}

class BaseViewModel
{
    public List<ViewmodelTask> Tasks
    {
        get
        {
            // Code to get the tasks from Database via Linq
        }
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**
Because I was not able to get the parent task to which the person belongs I simply added a member ParentTask to my person class. This member needs to be passed within the constructor. When the DeletePerson method is called on the ViewmodelPerson class the Object is deleted in the database and I have access to the parent Task object and can clean up the List as well. Afterwards ChangedProperty("Persons") of IPropertyChanged is called and the WPF tidies up the UI just like magic!

I was just wondering if this approach has a big impact on memory consumption if there are a lot of persons and tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a `ContextMenu`, but you can't access the `DataContext` of your view from its scope. This is a common problem in WPF and the solution is to 'put the `DataContext`' into a `Tag` property that we can later retrieve from the `ContextMenu`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourNamespace:YourDataType}">
    <Border Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={
x:Type YourViewNamespace:NameOfThisControl}}}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource 
YourContextMenu}">
        ...
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you need to set this `Tag` property to the `DataContext` of the `ContextMenu` using a handy property named `PlacementTarget`:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="YourContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Header="First Item" Command="{Binding CommandFromYourViewModel}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

To find out more, please take a look at the [Context Menus in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html) post on WPF Tutorial.NET.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I already read about this solution but it seems to be not very handy to me. I solved it the way mentioned in my first post. Thanks anyway!